# Definition of Lebesgue integral for simple functions

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading lecture notes on Measure theory and Integration and I ran into the following definition and lemma which confuses me a lot.

> **Definition 1:** Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function which takes on
>   only finitely many values and any non-zero value is achieved on the
>   set of finite measure. Then function $f(x)$ is called *simple*.
>
> **Definition 1':** The function $f(x)$ is *simple*, if $$f(x)=\sum  \limits_{k=1}^{n}c_k\chi_{E_k}(x),$$ where $E_k\in \mathcal{M}$,
>   $E_k\cap E_j=\varnothing$ for $k\neq j$ and $\mu(E_k)<\infty$ for
>   $c_k\neq 0$.
>
> **Remark:** We note that any simple function  can be written in the form $$f(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{m}a_i\chi_{F_i}(x)$$ $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_m$  and $\sqcup_{i=1}^{m}F_i=X$. This is called canonical representation of simple function.
>
> **Definition 2:** Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a simple function and $$f(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{m}a_i\chi_{F_i}(x)$$ is the canonical representation of $f(x)$. In this case we define *Lebesgue integral* of simple function $f(x)$ as follows:
>    $$(L)\int \limits_{X}f(x)d\mu=\int \limits_{X}f(x)d\mu:=\sum
>  \limits_{i=1}^{m}a_i\mu(F_i) \qquad \qquad(*)$$ (here we formally
>   assume that $0\times \infty=0$).
>
> **Lemma 1(unchanged).** The value of Lebesgue integral of simple function $f(x)$ does not depend on representation of $f(x)$ in the form $(*)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. If say, $c_1=c_2$, then you can define $E':=E_1\cup E_2$, and use that instead, to make $f$ canonical ($c_1<c_2,...$). In general any finite linear combination of indicator functions on measurable sets can be standardized by first making the sets disjoint (e.g. $E'_1=E_1, E'_2=E_2\backslash E_1, ...$) and then deriving the constants.

Comment: @AlexR., thanks a lot for your reply! Probably you are right since my question is not so clear. I will edit it.

Comment: At least I think that's what the author means in the Remark.

Comment: @AlexR., please take a look at my edit

Comment: @AlexR., I think we can define the simple function directly as in the remark. The definition where we say that some coefficients in $\sum a_k\chi_{F_k}$ may be equal seems to me meaningless.

Comment: I think this is just an example of minimal definitions. The ordering of $c_i$ is a "WLOG" consequence, which doesn't really add anything to the definition of a Lebesgue integral. The most important point is that the sets $E_i$ are disjoint, which plays nicely with the additive properties of measures. 

It's like saying, instead of finite sets being $\{3,1,2\}$, we're now going to define finite sets as ordered $\{1,2,3\}$, which might be convenient in some situations but adds nothing to the axiomatic framework of sets. It also fails miserably when you move onto infinite sets.

Comment: @AlexR., to be honest I did not get you at all.

Comment: But why do we need this lemma? As I said above we can define Lebesgue integral directly through canonical form. For the first time when you learning measure theory it is really confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, just some observations.

I think the presentation is a little confusing.

There are three characters in play.

Let me give my own name to the three things: (i) **simple functions** (Definition 1, finite range, finite support, the $E_k$ are disjoint), (ii) **partition simple functions** (the $E_k$ form a partition of $X$ and the $c_k$ need not be distinct) and (iii) **'ordered' canonical simple functions** (as in the Remark, the $c_k$ are ordered **and** the $E_k$ are 'maximal').

(I have no idea why the author introduces the notion of ordered $c_k$.)

The author defines the integral in terms of (ii), the partition simple functions. Note that this representation is **not** unique. The $c_k$ may be repeated and hence the $E_k$ are not necessarily maximal.

For example, $1_{[0,2]} + 0\cdot 1_{[0,2]^c} = 1_{[0,1)} + 1_{[1,2]} + 0\cdot 1_{[0,2]^c}$
are two (partition simple function) representations of the same simple function. Obviously we have $1 \cdot m([0,2]) + 0 \cdot \infty = 1 \cdot m([0,1)) + 1 \cdot m([2,1]) + 0 \cdot \infty$, but the result still needs to be established formally so that Definition 2 makes sense.

So, a priori, the definition is ambiguous. Hence the author needs Lemma 1 to establish that any of the partition simple function representations gives the same value for the integral.

(As an aside, note that Lemma 1 is the first step in showing that the integral is linear.)

Personally I would prefer to define the integral in terms of a canonical representation (I am willing to forgo the ordering :-)) and then show that any other representation yields the same integral.

Comment: Excellent! I read your answer but did not pay attention to the details but I guess this is what I want. Can I clarify some moments of your answer?

Comment: After day of thinking i came to conclusion that it is better to define Lebesgue integral in terms of canonical representation.

Comment: I would agree. ${}$

Comment: I modified the content of my topic. Please take a look. I guess it looks much better. I have few question: 1) I did not change the Lemma. How to formulate this Lemma in better way?

Comment: Looks good. I see now what the ordering $a_1<...< a_n$ does, it forces the $E_k$ to be maximal. I did not realise this earlier.

Comment: My question is how to write this lemma in better way? Could you help me please?

Comment: I have a stupid question: How definition 1' follows from definition 1? I am so confused with all this.

Comment: In other words, if $f(x)$ is a measurable function whose range is finite and has finite support then it can be written as a $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}c_k \chi_{E_k}(x)$ where $E_k$ are measurable, disjoint and $c_k$ are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: Definition 1' requires that the $E_k$ be disjoint. Definition 1 says nothing about the representation.

Comment: You need to show that if $\sum_k c_k 1_{D_k}$ is simple and $\sum_i a_i 1_{E_i}$ is the canonical representation then $\sum_k c_k \mu {D_k} = \sum_i a_i \mu{E_i}$.

Comment: How did you end up with two different definitions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107435/discussion-between-zfr-and-copper-hat).

Comment: Probably I am so lost that I wrote smth non-sense ... ok let's do the following: Let's pretend that we have only Definition 1. Forget about everything else. This definition 1 has only words. So how to write it with formulas?

Comment: I thought that definition 1' is the mathematical expression of definition 1.